# "Spread" in "I'm not into parlays and things of that nature, and when I think of the spread I think of the layout of food at any given game."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've found the sentence

> I'm not into parlays and things of that nature, and when I think of
>   the spread I think of the layout of food at any given game.

in the Oxford Dictionary under the [second definition for parlay](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/parlay):

> A cumulative series of bets in which winnings accruing from each
>   transaction are used as a stake for a further bet.

My understanding of the sentence is that *spread* means here the amount of stake the narrator would have to spend, and that he/she sees food in front of his/her mind's eye he'd/she'd rather like to spend this amount on. Am I correct with this interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted sentence expresses that the narrator is not particularly familiar with various forms of betting, in this case "parlay betting" and "spread betting".

The narrator is saying that when he/she hears the word "spread" in relation to a game, he/she doesn't think of betting, but of the food he/she might be able to eat there, using the following definition of spread:

> A large and impressively elaborate meal.

Comment: Also note the narrator's joking tone. The joke is enabled by the fact that "spread" is a technical sports/betting term, whereas "spread" in the food sense is more widely known — and probably comes to mind with more enthusiasm. :)